# Shifting elements by index and value in Java

Tags: java

I need to write a code that will shift elements to the right for k places, and the element is index position. Also I should suppose that my array List is linked in circle.

Example:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]; 
list.shiftRight(1,2); 
list = [1,3,4,2]
```

For the circle list I think of:

```
list = [1,2,3,4]; 
list.shiftRight(2, 3); 
list = [1,3,2,4].
```

This is my code but it's not working properly.

```
public void shiftRight(int index, int k) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{

    if (index < 0 || index > this.list.size())
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();

    if (k + index > this.list.size()) {
        int element = this.list.remove(index);
        this.list.add(this.list.size() - k, element);

    } else {
        int element = this.list.remove(index);
        this.list.add(k + index , element);

    }

    //System.out.println("ShiftedRight " + this.list);

}
```

Also here is the code for shifting elements to the left which also doesn't work. ^_^

```
public void shiftLeft(int index, int k) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

    if (index < 0 || index > this.list.size())
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();

    if (k + index > this.list.size()) {
        int element = this.list.remove(index);
        this.list.add(this.list.size() - k + index, element); 
    } else {
        int element = this.list.remove(index);
        this.list.add(index - k, element);
    }

    //System.out.println("ShiftedLeft " + this.list);

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the test code which shows it is not working? What happens when you step through the code in your debugger to help debug your program?

Comment: what is `list`? Why don't you just use the `set` method? It will return the old value to you. Instead of you having to remove it

Comment: http://prntscr.com/93lsom

Comment: What is type of list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. There are a few edge conditions to consider. And you have to be very careful with indexes, lengths and being off by one.

Firstly, note that in a list of 4 elements, the valid indexes are [0..3]. That is, the maximum index is one less than the length.

Secondly, k appears to be unbounded. I assume it's meant to be non-negative. If so, you should check for this. It can be many times larger than the length of the list, ie. you can loop around more than once. So we use modulo arithmetic.

Thirdly, when you remove an element from the list the indexes change. You need to handle this when adding the element back in.

```
public void shiftRight(int index, int k)
    throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
    int length = this.list.size();
    // Note: index cannot be equal to length. You were testing for >.
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= length))
    {
        throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException('out of range index: ' + index);
    }
    int shift = k % length; // Use modulo arithmetic to determine a shift in the range [0..length).
    if (shift == 0)
    {
         return; // No change, we're done.
    }
    int newIndex = (index + shift) % length; // Calculate where to move to, again using modulo arithmetic, to get the loop around.
    int element = this.list.remove(index);
    this.list.add(newIndex, element);
}
```

I've only hand-tested this so let me know if there are any issues. `shiftLeft()` should be similar, although watch out for negative numbers in modulo arithmetic.